# What happened to these comments?

Tags: discussion

A few hours ago, there were at least three comments on Bill Dubuque's answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/is-this-question-appropriate-1-5-2-10-etc/1471#1471). They no longer exist. Is there a reason they were removed, or is this a bug in the software?

Comment: Could someone reproduce these missing comments here?  People did take the time to write them.  It's not clear to me what makes them no longer valid or applicable.

Comment: @Pete: I have added an image to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bill deleted his answer and added a new one.

Added the lost comments, as per request:
[image]

Comment: Akhil's question says there were at least 3 comments--were there only these two?

Comment: @Isaac: Check the revision history of this answer. Bill didn't want his comment to be shown for some reason.

Comment: The comment was superseded by my revised post - which made my points more clearly and with less possibility for misinterpretation of motive.